# How to reference a control when it's id is stored in string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to update a textbox in code behind but I do not know the control id. However, the control id is being stored in the string `txtid`.

How do I pull the control id from the string then set a `.Text` property on it?

Comment: Are you thinking of [`Control.FindControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the reference to the control via ID. You need to use it on the control that is the [`NamingContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the control you're looking for. If the `TextBox` is directly on the page and you don't use a `MasterPage` you can use `Page.FindControl("ControlID")`:

```
TextBox textboxComments = (TextBox)this.FindControl(txtid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. For some reason, this stores a null value in `textboxComments`. Not sure why the value of `(TextBox)this.FindControl(txtid)` is not being passed. I've verified that the control id stored in `txtid` is a valid control on the page.

Comment: You have to tell or show where the control is sitting. As mentioned FindControl is not looking recursively. It just looks into the control container. If its for example in a GridView you have to use row.FindControl because the GridViewRow is the NamingContainer not the page.

Comment: Got it. It was in an Update Panel. Now it works with `TextBox textboxComments = (TextBox)TG_Panel.FindControl(txtid);`. Thanks again!